# react native geolocation does not work because of undefined getCurrentPosition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

When trying to retrieve the location of a user, it displays an error: 'Cannot read property getCurrentPosition' of undefined.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import Topnavbar from './TopNavbar'

class googleMapsImages extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ready: false, 
            where: {lat: null, lng: null},
            error: null
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        let geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeOut: 20000,
            maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24
        }
        this.setState({
            ready: false,
            error: null
        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 
            this.geoSucces, 
            this.geoFailure,
            geoOptions)
        }

        geoSucces = (position) => {
            this.setState({ready: true})
        }

        geoFailure = (err) => {
            this.setState({error: err.message})
        }
```

The docs say it does not require an import, so I don't see where i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install geolocation from react-native-community and then do 
navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');
Geolocation is not available by default in versions of react native >=0.60

Comment: after looking through it, this was the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I modified my usage with the following to get around the issue

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'


Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleSuccess, handleError, geoReqOptions)
```